# How to use ForEach Loop for DataBricks Notebook Json object output

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to fetch the notebook value(json value) to loop ForEach activity. how do we use this approach. also my goal is ForEach activity needs to all lookup activity to fetch some details from azure SQL DB to concatenate the values to send another notebook.

Kindly advice and possibility way to integrate.

sample JSON out from notebook

```
{
    "runPageUrl": "https://adb-url",
    "runOutput": {
        "value": {
            "xxxx": 60,
            "mmmm": "value",
            "db": "dbname",
            "table": "tablename",
            "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
            "aggvalue": [
                "value"
            ],
            "date_val": [
                "date_val"
            ]
        },
        "vlue2": "value": {
            "xxxx": 60,
            "mmmm": "value",
            "db": "dbname",
            "table": "tablename",
            "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
            "aggvalue": [
                "value"
            ],
            "date_val": [
                "date_val"
            ]
        },
        
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
    "executionDuration": 297,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.3343434,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    } }
```

Comment: You want to pass databricks Notebook output to a ForEach activity as an array?

Comment: Yes Rakesh, we are calling notebook first and will get JSON list of objects then needs to loop ForEach. and parallel we needs to fetch the Azure Sql DB to get list of some column details to merge with ForEach Result to prepare final dataset to use another notebook. please provide some inputs.

Comment: You want to iterate lookup activity inside ForEach? or Outside ForEach, you want merge the ForEach output array to lookup array?

Comment: anything fine, end of the day we needs to merge the equal  value to another notebook. let me know first steps the notebook A will give the JSON list of object and needs to loop or any mechanism to do the loop and apply lookup . lookup also will give the list of json data. in this regareds what is the best way to implement

Comment: if trying to iterate the json object not taking ForEach loop and getting failed

Comment: ERROR :
The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your JSON in my environment and found that your JSON is not valid with below error in databricks.

[image]

Then I used below JSON.

```
{
    "value": {
        "xxxx": 60,
        "mmmm": "value",
        "db": "dbname",
        "table": "tablename",
        "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
        "aggvalue": [
            "value"
        ],
        "date_val": [
            "date_val"
        ]
    },
    "value": {
        "xxxx": 60,
        "mmmm": "value",
        "db": "dbname",
        "table": "tablename",
        "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
        "aggvalue": [
            "value"
        ],
        "date_val": [
            "date_val"
        ]
    }}
```

When I execute the above JSON, you can see the same key `value` is updated.

[image]

When I pass the same JSON to ADF pipeline using `dbutils.notebook.exit(data)` and I have used the `@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput` dynamic content in the ForEach. You can see I got same error as yours.

[image]

As the error suggests, ForEach only supports array or string to iterate.

So, change your JSON like below (array of objects) and pass it to the ForEach which is good for iterating.

```
[
{
    "xxxx": 60,
    "mmmm": "value",
    "db": "dbname",
    "table": "tablename",
    "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
    "aggvalue": ["value"],
    "date_val": ["date_val"]
},
{
    "xxxx": 60,
    "mmmm": "value",
    "db": "dbname",
    "table": "tablename",
    "asset_id": "1cda102e-dddddxxxxx9c775",
    "aggvalue": ["value"],
    "date_val": ["date_val"]
}
]
```

[image]

Coming to using lookup values, **ForEach only supports iterating one array(Notebook output)**. So, if you want to concatenate the lookup values also inside this ForEach, both Notebook output array length and lookup output array length should be same.

Then you can iterate two arrays at a time by using an index array with ForEach activity.
To understand about iterating about 2 arrays at same time go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701965/adf-passing-more-than-one-array-paramater-to-logicapps/74713105#74713105).